# Pattern-matching Conditions using REGEXPR_SUBSTR in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have following clob column and I need to extract the RuleName from the below column using oracle.

**Clob column:**

"Declare ABBaseTransKey AB_Base_Trans.Key%type := :P_KEY;hRowID RowID;TestMode varchar2(1) := :TESTING;Dummy varchar2(1);RuleName varchar2(1000);IncreaseRunLevel boolean := false;Begin If TestMode = 'N' then select RowID into hRowID from AB_Base_Trans where Key = ABBaseTransKey;end if;
**RuleName** := 'HKG-MRG-UA-PRODUCT-CATEGORY/UA/UA01';update ab_base_trans set CC_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = 'CROSS DOCK' where Key = ABBaseTransKey and RowID = hRowID and Client_ID = 'UA' and Site_ID = 'UA01' and TestMode = 'N' and  (DOC_TYPE = 'A'  AND  ((LOTTABLE_07 = 'TRANSLOAD') OR (LOTTABLE_07 = 'UARESERVED')));
**RuleName** := 'HKG-MRG-UA-PRODUCT-CATEGORY-PIKPAK/UA/UA01';update ab_base_trans set CC_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = 'PICK PACK' where Key = ABBaseTransKey and RowID = hRowID and Client_ID = 'UA' and Site_ID = 'UA01' and TestMode = 'N' and  (DOC_TYPE = 'A'  AND  ((LOTTABLE_07 <> 'TRANSLOAD') AND (LOTTABLE_07 <> 'UARESERVED')));
RuleName := 'HKG-MRG-UA-RTN-RCPT/UA/UA01';update ab_base_trans set CC_BILLABLE_QUANTITY =  ABS(BILLABLE_QUANTITY) where Key = ABBaseTransKey and RowID = hRowID and Client_ID = 'UA' and Site_ID = 'UA01' and TestMode = 'N' and  (Doc_Type = 'J' and Doc_Sub_Type = 'RET');
**RuleName** := 'HKG-MRG-UA-SPECIAL-RATE-CODE/UA/UA01';update ab_base_trans set CC_Special_Rate_Code = 'SMS' where Key = ABBaseTransKey and RowID = hRowID and Client_ID = 'UA' and Site_ID = 'UA01' and TestMode = 'N' and  (((DOC_TYPE = 'A') OR (DOC_TYPE = 'N') OR (DOC_TYPE = 'P')) AND  ((SUBSTR(LOTTABLE_01,1,1) = 'S') OR(SUBSTR(LOTTABLE_01,1,1) = 'M')) AND (END_DSTAMP  BETWEEN (SELECT USER_DEF_DATE_1 FROM CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_ID='UA') AND (SELECT USER_DEF_DATE_2 FROM CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_ID='UA')));
**RuleName** := 'HKG-MRG-UA-SPECIAL-RATE-CODE-NA/UA/UA01';update ab_base_trans set CC_Special_Rate_Code = 'NA' where Key = ABBaseTransKey and RowID = hRowID and Client_ID = 'UA' and Site_ID = 'UA01' and TestMode = 'N' and  (NOT( ((DOC_TYPE = 'A') OR (DOC_TYPE = 'N') OR (DOC_TYPE = 'P')) AND  ((SUBSTR(LOTTABLE_01,1,1) = 'S') OR(SUBSTR(LOTTABLE_01,1,1) = 'M')) AND (END_DSTAMP  BETWEEN (SELECT USER_DEF_DATE_1 FROM CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_ID='UA') AND (SELECT USER_DEF_DATE_2 FROM CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_ID='UA')) ));
**RuleName** := 'HKG-MRG-UA-VAS-LABEL-COUNT-BASE/UA/UA01';update ab_base_trans set CC_LABEL_COUNT = Billable_Carton * R_LABEL_COUNT where Key = ABBaseTransKey and RowID = hRowID and Client_ID = 'UA' and Site_ID = 'UA01' and TestMode = 'N' and  (DOC_TYPE = 'LABEL');
<> LibABBaseTransMergeRule.SetIncreaseRunLevel (IncreaseRunLevel); Null; Exception when others then LibABBaseTransMergeRule.SetErrorCode (ABBaseTransKey, RuleName, 'UA', 'UA01', sqlerrm); LibABBaseTransMergeRule.SetIncreaseRunLevel (false); Raise; End;"

Comment: @koushik : The modified code whole single string and I need to match only rulename.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one isn't a *hi-tech* option, but - see if it helps.

- `t1` CTE returns all parts that contain "RuleName :=" string to the length of 100 characters (is it long enough?)
- the final `SELECT` then returns substring which ends with a slash

There might be further adjustments (is it always "RuleName" (letter case), does it always have just one space between that name and "=", etc.) but - might be OK as a first step.

```
SQL> with t1 as
  2    (select substr(col, instr(col, 'RuleName :=', 1, level) + 13, 100) res1
  3     from a
  4     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, 'RuleName :=')
  5    )
  6  select substr(res1, 1, instr(res1, '/') - 1) result
  7  from t1;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HKG-MRG-UA-PRODUCT-CATEGORY
HKG-MRG-UA-PRODUCT-CATEGORY-PIKPAK
HKG-MRG-UA-RTN-RCPT
HKG-MRG-UA-SPECIAL-RATE-CODE
HKG-MRG-UA-SPECIAL-RATE-CODE-NA
HKG-MRG-UA-VAS-LABEL-COUNT-BASE

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Though, if you only want to know whether certain RuleName exists in that column, `INSTR` is enough:

```
SQL> select case when instr(col, 'HKG-MRG-UA-RTN-RCPT') > 0 then 'It exists'
  2              else 'It does not exist'
  3         end result
  4  from a;

RESULT
-----------------
It exists

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one RuleName given and need to match with the result if that RuleName is exists with the result. Also the result is giving as HKG-MRG-UA-PRODUCT-CATEGORY/UA/UA01 I need to match only HKG-MRG-UA-PRODUCT-CATEGORY

Comment: Well, you didn't say that in the question. I have now modified the query and added option which says whether certain RuleName exists or not.